# PerL SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssl, curl, openssl

I'm hoping someone can help, I'm using the nagios plugin check_ilo2_health, the plugin works fine on our OpenSuSE systems but the new Ubuntu 14.04 system has issues, removing the nagios stuff and running perl, is basically this:

```
perl -e 'use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);IO::Socket::SSL->new(SSL_hostname => "", PeerAddr=>"10.0.0.1:443",  Proto=>"tcp",SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE)or die $!'
```

I'm connecting to an HP ILO2 with a self signed certificate and get a reply:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2503: new ctx 19182624
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:526: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:528: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:550: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:586: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:647: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:695: connection failed - connect returned 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1757: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2537: free ctx 19182624 open=19182624
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2549: OK free ctx 19182624
IO::Socket::SSL: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac        ...propagated at -e line 1.
```

If I run it in curl:

```
curl "https://10.0.0.1" --insecure
```

It works returning the page from the ILO.

I want to tell perl or openSSL to ignore any certificate problems as this is a monitoring system and a lot of the servers use self signed certificates.

Any ideas of what can be done?

Versions:

```
Perl Version: This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Crypt::SSLeay   0.72
IO::Socket::SSL 1.997
Net::SSLeay     1.66
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to tell perl or openSSL to ignore any certificate problems as this is a monitoring system and a lot of the servers use self signed certificates.

You are doing it correctly, that is by using SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE.

> IO::Socket::SSL: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac        ...propagated at -e line 1.

Strange, but I've seen other reports with "HP ILO2" and bad_record_mac.
Try to reduce the version to SSL 3.0, e.g. `SSL_version => "SSLv3"`.

But because SSL 3.0 would not be a satisfactory solution because of POODLE I would be interested to have a look at the working SSL handshake from curl (upload to cloudshark.org).

Comment: I'm on a secure network so I can't use cloudshark, however that did fix the issue thank-you.  Looking at curl it's also using SSL3 handshake then creates a connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

Answer (score 0):

The same error happens with Net::LDAP (which also uses IO::Socket::SSL) when connecting to a server that only supports SSLv2.

IO::Socket::SSL "auto-negotiates between SSLv2 and SSLv3" by default according to man page, so omitting SSL_version allows scripts to work with older servers.

Or, more optimistically, the script will still work when the administrator gets around to upgrading the server!