# SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems using Net::FTPSSL

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to create a Perl script with `Net::FTPSSL` that move the files from the FTP server to actual server.

The script will run every X minutes / seconds to check if the customers uploaded something new on the FTP server and move it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use Net::FTPSSL;

my $ftp;   
  
sub connect_ftp {
    $ftp = Net::FTPSSL->new('sftp.domain.com',
                            Encryption => EXP_CRYPT,
                            Debug => 1, DebugLogFile => "/usr/logs/ftpssl.log");
    $ftp->login('username', 'password');
    $ftp->binary();
}

sub copy_files {
    my @folder_list;
    my $folder;

    @folder_list = $ftp->nlst();

    foreach $folder (@folder_list) {
        if ($folder ne "globa_username") {
            $ftp->cwd($folder);

            my @file_list;
            my $video;

            @file_list = $ftp->nlst();

            foreach $video (@file_list) {
                my $file_status;
                my $result;

                if ($video =~ /\.mp4$/i) {
                    if (!file_exist($video, $folder)) {
                        $file_status = $ftp->is_file($video);

                        if ($file_status > 0) {
                            $result = $ftp->get($video, "/usr/media/$folder/$video");
                            if (defined $result) {
                                #$ftp->delete($video);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                
        $ftp->cdup();
    }
        
    #$ftp->quit();
}

sub file_exist {
    my ($video, $folder) = @_;
    return -f "/usr/media/$folder/$video";
}    

connect_ftp();

for (;;) {
    copy_files();
    #sleep 60;
    #sleep 30;
}
```

The script works fine until returns: `**555 TLSv12: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems**`.

```
Net-FTPSSL Version: 0.42
IO-Socket-SSL Version: 1.94
Net-SSLeay Version: 1.55
IO-Socket-INET Version: 1.33
IO-Socket-INET6 might not be installed.
IO-Socket-IP Version: 0.21
IO Version: 1.25_06
Socket Version: 2.030

No IPv6 support available.  You must 1st upgrade IO::Socket::SSL to support it!

Perl: 5.016003  [5.16.3],  OS: linux

***** IPv6 not yet supported in Net::FTPSSL! *****

Server (port): sftp.domain.com (21)

Keys: (Debug), (Encryption), (DebugLogFile)
Values: (1), (E), (/usr/logs/ftpssl.log)

SKT <<< 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
SKT >>> AUTH TLS
SKT <<< 234 Proceed with negotiation.

Object HASH Details ... (SSL:arguments - E)
  SSL_hostname ==> sftp.domain.com
  SSL_verify_mode ==> 0
  SSL_version ==> TLSv12
  Timeout ==> 120


Object Net::FTPSSL Details ... (sftp.domain.com:21 - E)
  _FTPSSL_arguments ==> HASH(0x272cee8)
      -- Croak ===> (undef)
      -- Crypt ===> E
      -- FixGetTs ===> 0
      -- FixPutTs ===> 0
      -- Host ===> sftp.domain.com
      -- Pret ===> 0
      -- Timeout ===> 120
      -- buf_size ===> 10240
      -- data_prot ===> P
      -- dcsc_mode ===> 1
      -- debug ===> 2
      -- debug_extra ===> 0
      -- debug_no_help ===> 0
      -- ftpssl_filehandle ===> GLOB(0x2a6d8c8)
      -- last_ftp_msg ===> 234 Proceed with negotiation.
      -- myContext ===> HASH(0x2747d18)
          -- SSL_ca_file ----> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
          -- SSL_reuse_ctx ----> IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_Context=HASH(0x2a8f1f0)
              -- context ++++> 44543648
      -- mySocketOpts ===> HASH(0x2746ec0)
          -- PeerAddr ----> sftp.domain.com
          -- PeerPort ----> 21
          -- Proto ----> tcp
          -- Timeout ----> 120
      -- start_SSL_opts ===> HASH(0x272c840)
          -- SSL_hostname ----> sftp.domain.com
          -- SSL_verify_mode ----> 0
          -- SSL_version ----> TLSv12
          -- Timeout ----> 120
      -- trace ===> 0
      -- type ===> A
  _SSL_arguments ==> HASH(0x2a8e770)
      -- PeerAddr ===> 33.44.55.66
      -- PeerPort ===> 21
      -- Proto ===> tcp
      -- SSL_ca_file ===> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
      -- SSL_cert_file ===> certs/client-cert.pem
      -- SSL_check_crl ===> 0
      -- SSL_honor_cipher_order ===> 0
      -- SSL_hostname ===> sftp.domain.com
      -- SSL_key_file ===> certs/client-key.pem
      -- SSL_server ===> 0
      -- SSL_use_cert ===> 0
      -- SSL_verify_mode ===> 0
      -- SSL_version ===> TLSv12
  _SSL_ctx ==> IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_Context=HASH(0x2a8f1f0)
      -- context ===> 44543648
  _SSL_fileno ==> 4
  _SSL_ioclass_upgraded ==> IO::Socket::INET
  _SSL_last_err ==> SSL wants a read first
  _SSL_object ==> 44657040
  _SSL_opened ==> 1
  io_socket_domain ==> 2
  io_socket_proto ==> 6
  io_socket_timeout ==> 120
  io_socket_type ==> 1
************************************************************
>>> USER +++++++
<<< 331 Please specify the password.
>>> PASS *******
<<< 230 Login successful.
>>> HELP
<<< 214-The following commands are recognized.
<<<  ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
<<<  MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
<<<  RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
<<<  XPWD XRMD
<<< 214 Help OK.
>>> FEAT
<<< 211-Features:
<<<  AUTH SSL
<<<  AUTH TLS
<<<  EPRT
<<<  EPSV
<<<  MDTM
<<<  PASV
<<<  PBSZ
<<<  PROT
<<<  REST STREAM
<<<  SIZE
<<<  TVFS
<<<  UTF8
<<< 211 End
<<+ 111 Auto-adding OPTS Command!
>>> HELP SITE
<<< 214-The following commands are recognized.
<<<  ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
<<<  MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
<<<  RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
<<<  XPWD XRMD
<<< 214 Help OK.
>>> SITE HELP
<<< 214 CHMOD UMASK HELP
<<+ 214 The HELP command is supported.
>>> TYPE I
<<< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
<<< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
>>> PBSZ 0
<<< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
>>> PROT P
<<< 200 PROT now Private.
>>> PASV
<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,20,207).
--- Host (33.44.55.66)  Port (5327)
>>> NLST
<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
<<< 226 Directory send OK.
>>> CWD demo3
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> PBSZ 0
<<< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
>>> PROT P
<<< 200 PROT now Private.
>>> PASV
<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,20,144).
--- Host (33.44.55.66)  Port (5264)
>>> NLST
<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
<<< 226 Directory send OK.
>>> CDUP
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> CDUP
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> CWD demo2
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> PBSZ 0
<<< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
>>> PROT P
<<< 200 PROT now Private.
>>> PASV
<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,20,179).
--- Host (33.44.55.66)  Port (5299)
>>> NLST
<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
<<< 226 Directory send OK.
>>> CDUP
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> CWD demo
<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
>>> PBSZ 0
<<< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
>>> PROT P
<<< 200 PROT now Private.
>>> PASV
...
<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,19,196).
--- Host (33.44.55.66)  Port (5060)
>>> NLST
<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
<<+ 555 TLSv12: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
>>> PBSZ 0
<<+ 555 Unexpected EOF on Command Channel [0] (0, 1) ()
>>> PROT P
<<+ 555 Can't write command on socket:
```

**UPDATE:**

Tried downgrading SSL_version to SSLv3 but it still doesn't work.

```
$ftp = Net::FTPSSL->new('sftp.domain.com',
                            Encryption => EXP_CRYPT,
                            Debug => 1, DebugLogFile => "/usr/logs/ftpssl.log", SSL_version => "SSLv3");
```

**Net::FTP**

I created another script using `Net::FTP` it's works fine until:

```
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(3.11)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.68)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(3.11)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::SSL(2.072)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket::INET(1.33)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Socket(1.34)
Net::FTP>>>         IO::Handle(1.33)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> AUTH TLS
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 234 Proceed with negotiation.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> PBSZ 0
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 200 PBSZ set to 0.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> PROT P
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 200 PROT now Private.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> USER username
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 331 Please specify the password.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 230 Login successful.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> TYPE I
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,21,107).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> NLST
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 226 Directory send OK.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> CWD demo
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x11d7400)>>> PASV
...
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)<<< 226 Directory send OK.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)>>> CWD demo3
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)<<< 250 Directory successfully changed.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (33,44,55,66,19,196).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)>>> NLST
failed to ssl upgrade dataconn: SSL wants a read first at ./upload_ftp.pl line 40.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)<<< 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x13e2400)>>> CDUP
Net::FTP: Net::Cmd::getline(): unexpected EOF on command channel:  at ./upload_ftp.pl line 56.
Net::FTP: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:  at ./upload_ftp.pl line 56.
```

Comment: Googling your error message returned [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629638/perl-ssl-connect-attempt-failed-because-of-handshake-problems) as the first result. The answer might be useful to you.

Comment: I found that answer but was thinking it doesn't apply. I will let you know if it solves my question.

Comment: Handshake failure can be anything. But one things stands out is that Net::FTPSSL by default tries to enforce TLS 1.2, which the server might or might not support. Is there any reason you use Net::FTPSSL given that the core module NET::FTP has support for SSL for a long time too? And it does not enforce a specific TLS version either. *"I try to use sleep but problem persist."* - I can imagine no reason why a sleep could have solved a SSL handshake problem.

Comment: *"IO-Socket-SSL Version: 1.94"* - yuck, this is 8 years old!! If the rest of your software stack is of similar age then it might simply be too old to be usable with this FTP server. *"Tried downgrading SSL_version to SSLv3 ...."* - I hope the server does not support SSL 3.0 anymore since this is insecure and therefore obsolete for years. You might try `TLSv1` instead. Or use `SSLv23` as setting for the version.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I already tried Net:FTP. If I doesn't use `SSL` it return: `530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.` but If I set `SSL => 1, Port => 21` it return:  `SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown`

Comment: @cplaiuu: `SSL => 1` is only for SSL from start, typically on port 990. For port 21 you need to use SSL after an initial plain connect, i.e. [starttls](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#starttls()).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried `Net::FTP` but it keeps crashing.  I update my question. Could you take a look at it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239000/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-cplaiuu).